# Restrict WordPress to Private

Tags: private

I want to set up a private WordPress site, with only 2 users, all I need is a simple private site functionality, with visitors unable to see anything when trying to login, only being redirected to the login page. RSS should also be blocked.

I have found one plugin which does this, but it doesn't seem to be maintained, any others which do the same thing and are maintained?

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members-only/

Comment: Do you want the content to be public or private? Is it just the back-end features that you want to be private?

Comment: no I am using P2 theme for WordPress and I want the site to be internal so we can collaborate without the content being accessible to anyone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this :

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/password-protected/

> A very simple way to quickly password protect your WordPress site with
>   a single password. Integrates seamlessly into your WordPress privacy
>   settings.
>
> **How can I change the WordPress logo to a different image?**
>
> Install and configure the Login Logo plugin by Mark Jaquith. This will
>   change the logo on your password entry page AND also your admin login
>   page.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you can, use apache basic authentication, much easier than trying to do this with a WP plugin, especially if you only have 2 users for the site.

Comment: The advantage of this approach is that it provides umbrella security at a lower level. No need to worry about hackers working around wordpress security if you're using apache's security instead. Not sure if it's "easier" really. Setting up a htaccess file isn't exactly "point and click" easy. Also this approach is inelegant in some ways. The htaccess pop-up (depends on the browser but) generally feels crude and ugly. And this will mean the admin user(s) has to login twice. Once via the htaccess pop-up, and once with the wordpress login screen.

Answer (score 3):

See [WordPress › Absolute Privacy « WordPress Plugins.](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/absolute-privacy/) Full login control and blocking of RSS.

Answer (score 2):

I've been working on this a little bit, and this solution adds a new set of options to the "Privacy" settings page.

```
function oxide_setup_options() {
    register_setting('oxide-privacy', 'blog_open');
    $blog_open = get_option('blog_open');
    if ( empty( $blog_open ) ) {
        add_option('blog_open', '0');
    }
}
add_action('admin_init', 'oxide_setup_options');
function oxide_restrict_toggle() { ?>
<?php settings_fields('oxide-privacy'); ?>
<legend class="screen-reader-text"><span><?php _e( 'Site Access Restriction' ); ?> </span></legend>
<input id="blog-open" type="radio" name="blog_open" value="1" <?php checked('1', get_option('blog_open')); ?> />
<label for="blog-open"><?php _e( 'Allow access to all users.' );?></label><br/>
<input id="blog-closed" type="radio" name="blog_open" value="0" <?php checked('0', get_option('blog_open')); ?> />
<label for="blog-closed"><?php _e( 'Restrict access to logged in users.' ); ?></label>
<p class="description"><?php _e( 'Note: This option blocks access to your site &mdash; like a boss.' ); ?></p>
<?php do_settings_fields('oxide-privacy', 'default'); ?>
<?php }
add_action('blog_privacy_selector', 'oxide_restrict_toggle');
function oxide_restrict_access() {
    if ( !get_option('blog_open') && !is_user_logged_in() ) {
        wp_redirect( wp_login_url() ); exit;
    }
}
add_action('parse_request', 'oxide_restrict_access');
```

[image: screenshot of the Privacy Options screen after implementation]

Just toss that code into your theme's functions.php file or create a simple plugin containing the code and you're well on your way!

Comment: I find it hard to believe that hacking around with php files is the best solution to this... but I can confirm I have tried this and it works. Thanks! Also it *does* block access to the RSS too.